# Wordpress Buddypress, Show user role next to Displayed Name

Tags: wordpress, users, plugin

I have a litle question. I want to see the primary role of the user next to the displayed name in activity, profile, and more. Did enyone know how I can do this?

[image]

[image]

Thanks for awnser.

Comment: Additionally WordPress PHP/CSS/HTML editing related questions are off-topic on Pro Webmasters.